# How to connect via virtio GUI running on host with GPIO in a QEMU-emulated virtual machine?

Tags: qemu, gpio, virtio

Some time ago, I asked a similar question, ["How to connect GPIO in QEMU-emulated machine to an object in host?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764018/how-to-connect-gpio-in-qemu-emulated-machine-to-an-object-in-host) and after some work, I have found a not perfect but satisfactory [solution](https://github.com/wzab/BR_Internet_Radio/tree/gpio_simple_2021.02/QemuVirt64).

However, now we have [virtio](https://github.com/oasis-tcs/virtio-spec) that [supports GPIO](https://github.com/oasis-tcs/virtio-spec/tree/master/device-types/gpio), and it would be good to use that solution instead of a [modified mpc8xxx](https://github.com/wzab/BR_Internet_Radio/blob/gpio_simple_2021.02/QemuVirt64/patches/1001-BR-WZab-host-qemu-mpc8xxx-patched-for-GUI-virt-added.patch) driver.
That previous solution was not perfect and difficult to maintain (I have only ported it to Buildroot 2021.02 and stopped further maintenance).

Unfortunately, I don't see any implementation of host-side virtio-user-gpio that I could use to connect GUI to a machine emulated in QEMU.

Is there any library (preferably with Python bindings) that could facilitate this task?
Should I start from scratch, implementing the virtio protocol for the GPIO device as defined in the [specification](https://github.com/oasis-tcs/virtio-spec)?

Comment: I tried to implement a simple Python server listening on a TCP/IP port and have QEMU connected to it by adding 
`-device vhost-user-gpio-pci,chardev=cg0 -chardev socket,id=cg0,host="127.0.0.1",port="4321"`
Hovewer, after an attempt to connect I get:
`qemu-system-aarch64: -device vhost-user-gpio-pci,chardev=cg0: Failed to set msg fds.
qemu-system-aarch64: ../hw/virtio/vhost.c:1633: vhost_dev_get_config: Assertion 'hdev->vhost_ops' failed.`

Comment: I have moved my server from TCP/IP socket to UNIX socket, and now I get a single message: `"b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'"`. According to  https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/interop/vhost-user.html#message-specification and https://elixir.bootlin.com/qemu/v7.2.1/source/subprojects/libvhost-user/libvhost-user.h#L75 it looks like a  VHOST_USER_GET_FEATURES request. It seems that implementation of Python based vhost backend is possible ;-). The cause of the previous problem was using a TCP/IP instead of a UNIX socket.

Comment: Yet another possibility may connecting the Rust implementation of vhost-user-gpio ( https://github.com/rust-vmm/vhost-device ) to the Python-implemented GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after almost a year, I have found an answer to my question.
Indeed, the right solution was based on [Rust implementation of vhost-user-gpio](https://github.com/rust-vmm/vhost-device). I have created [my own fork](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device), with the solution in [the branch gpio-python](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/tree/gpio-python/vhost-device-gpio).

I have  modified the implementation of the [MockGpioDevice](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/src/mock_gpio.rs#L20), making it connect to the JSON RPC server using the simple HTTP transport:

```rust
use jsonrpc::Client;
use jsonrpc::simple_http::{self, SimpleHttpTransport};
use serde_json::json;
use serde_json::value::to_raw_value;

fn client() -> std::result::Result<Client,simple_http::Error> {
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8001";
    let t = SimpleHttpTransport::builder()
        .url(url)?
        .build();

    Ok(Client::with_transport(t))
}

fn call(cli : &Client, fun : &str, param : serde_json::Value ) -> serde_json::Value
{
   let raw_value = Some(to_raw_value(&param).unwrap());
   let request = cli.build_request(fun, raw_value.as_deref());
   let response = cli.send_request(request).expect("send_request failed");
   let resp2 : serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str((*response.result.unwrap()).get()).unwrap(); 
   return resp2;
}
```

The individual functions handling changes in the state of GPIOs do the RPC calls. For example the [reading](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/src/mock_gpio.rs#L148) and [writing](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/src/mock_gpio.rs#L159) of the GPIO pin is implemented as follows:

```rust
    fn value(&self, gpio: u16) -> Result<u8> {
        if self.value_result.is_err() {
            return self.value_result;
        }
    let resp = call(&self.rpc_client,"value",json!([gpio]));
        println!("{:?}",resp);
        let val : u8 = resp[1].as_u64().unwrap().try_into().unwrap() ;
        return Ok(val);
    
    }

    fn set_value(&self, gpio: u16, value: u32) -> Result<()> {
        info!(
            "gpio {} set value to {}",
            self.gpio_names[gpio as usize], value
        );
        if self.set_value_result.is_err() {
            return self.set_value_result;
        }
    let resp = call(&self.rpc_client,"set_value",json!([gpio,value]));
        println!("{:?}",resp);
        return Ok(());
    }
```

The [JSON RPC server](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/py/rpc.py) is implemented in Python using tinyrpc. It is connected to the [Gtk GUI](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/py/gui3.py) adapted from [my old solution](https://github.com/wzab/BR_Internet_Radio/tree/gpio_simple_2021.02/QemuVirt64).

The corresponding [read](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/py/rpc.py#L66) and [write](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/py/rpc.py#L70) pin implementations are very simple.

```py
@dispatcher.public
def value(n):
    return ("OK",gpios[n].val)

@dispatcher.public
def set_value(n,v):
    gpios[n].val = v
    rpc_server.change_handler(n,v)
    return ("OK")
```

The field `val` is modified by the [send_change](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/py/gui3.py#L50) function in GUI:

```py
def send_change(nof_pin, state):
    do_irq = (rpc.gpios[nof_pin].val != state)
    rpc.gpios[nof_pin].val = state
    if do_irq:
        with rpc.gpios[nof_pin].wait_both:
            rpc.gpios[nof_pin].wait_both.notify_all()
        if state == 1:
            with rpc.gpios[nof_pin].wait_rise:
                rpc.gpios[nof_pin].wait_rise.notify_all()
        if state == 0:
            with rpc.gpios[nof_pin].wait_fall:
                rpc.gpios[nof_pin].wait_fall.notify_all()
```

That function also supports handling the GPIO-generated interrupts with the [wait_for_interrupt](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/py/rpc.py#L81) function.

```py
def wait_for_interrupt(n):
    if gpios[n].irq_type == 1: # RISING
       with gpios[n].wait_rise:
           gpios[n].wait_rise.wait()
    if gpios[n].irq_type == 2: # FALLING
       with gpios[n].wait_fall:
          gpios[n].wait_fall.wait()
    if gpios[n].irq_type == 3: # BOTH
       with gpios[n].wait_both:
           gpios[n].wait_both.wait()
    return ("OK",1)
```

The corresponding [function](https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/blob/e9af7d96773b496b6e1947ead89b0ab85dc18194/vhost-device-gpio/src/mock_gpio.rs#L186) in the vhost-device-gpio is the following:

```rust
    fn wait_for_interrupt(&self, gpio: u16) -> Result<bool> {
        if self.wait_for_irq_result.is_err() {
            return self.wait_for_irq_result;
        }
        let resp = call(&self.rpc_client,"wait_for_interrupt",json!([gpio]));
        println!("{:?}",resp);
        let val : bool = resp[1].as_u64().unwrap() > 0;
        return Ok(val);
    }
```

For testing, I first started the GUI by running `python3 gui3.py` in the virtual environment with installed: `tinyrpc`, `gevent`, `werkzeug`, and `pgi`.
Then I started the vhost-device-gpio:

```bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/emb/libgpiod-2.1/lib/.libs/ ./vhost-device-gpio -s /tmp/gpio.sock -l s1
```

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH must be set because, in my Debian/testing machine, an old libgpiod is used. Therefore, I had to compile the new version in `/home/emb/libgpiod-2.1`. Of course, the `vhost-device-gpio` also needed to be built specially:

```bash
export PATH_TO_LIBGPIOD=/home/emb/libgpiod-2.1
export SYSTEM_DEPS_LIBGPIOD_NO_PKG_CONFIG=1
export SYSTEM_DEPS_LIBGPIOD_SEARCH_NATIVE="${PATH_TO_LIBGPIOD}/lib/.libs/"
export SYSTEM_DEPS_LIBGPIOD_LIB=gpiod
export SYSTEM_DEPS_LIBGPIOD_INCLUDE="${PATH_TO_LIBGPIOD}/include/"
cargo build --features "mock_gpio"
```

When GUI and vhost-device-gpio were started, I could run the QEMU with a guest OS connecting to my emulated GPIO. I have used Linux built for `qemu-aarch64-virt` platform with Buildroot 2023.11.1 for that purpose.

Of course, I had to enable  `CONFIG_GPIO_VIRTIO=m` in the Linux kernel configuration. To emulate GPIO interrupts, the QEMU had to be patched, as described [here](https://github.com/rust-vmm/vhost-device/issues/613).

The QEMU was started with the following additional arguments:

```
-chardev socket,path=/tmp/gpio.sock0,id=vgpio \
-device vhost-user-gpio-pci,chardev=vgpio,id=gpio \
-object memory-backend-file,id=mem,size=1G,mem-path=/dev/shm,share=on \
-numa node,memdev=mem  \
```

After the emulated machine starts, it is possible to load the driver: `modprobe gpio-virtio`. Then it is possible to test interrupts with `gpiomon 0 12`, read pins with `gpioget 0 4` or write them with `gpioset 0 24` (of course you may change the pin numbers).

The described solution is only a proof of the concept. Error detection and handling are almost non-existent.  Also, stopping the emulation when the guest waits for the interrupt may be difficult. However, I hope this may be a good starting point for further development.

Comment: Reading and writing pins with the above method works OK, but handling the interrupts is not reliable. If the thread waits too long for the interrupt, it fails with: `thread '<unnamed>' panicked at vhost-device-gpio/src/mock_gpio.rs:38:45:
send_request failed: Transport(SocketError(Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }))
note: run with "RUST_BACKTRACE=1" environment variable to display a backtrace`

Comment: I have modified handling of interrupts with https://github.com/wzab/vhost-device/commit/23b960820ad77525006108de6d99ee2d915ab88a . However, it is still not perfect. There is a small time period between two calls to `wait` when the change of the pin state may be overlooked.

Comment: I have created an easy to use demo integrating the above described solutions.
It is available at https://github.com/wzab/gpio-qemu-demo .